# Binding data to a Scrollview Stacklayout in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding

I saw an article on xamarin forms with some "Bindable love" https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-forms-3-5-a-little-bindable-love/.

I wanted to try it out and create a scrolling list but for some reason, the data that i am binding does not seem to appear in the view. The binding should work fine because in my XAML i bind plenty of other things and it works successfully, but for some reason this particular binding is not working.

XAML:

```
<ScrollView>
   <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CategoriesList}"  >
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>         
                           <StackLayout Orientation = "Horizontal" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="80">

                                <Button Text="{Binding Name}" />

                         </StackLayout>
                       </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>          
             </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

This is how my list looks in the VM:

```
private ObservableCollection<Categories> _Categories;
    public ObservableCollection<Categories> CategoriesList
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Categories;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Categories != value)
            {
                this._Categories = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CategoriesList");
            }
        }
    }
```

And when i create data to it:

```
        CategoriesList = new ObservableCollection<Categories>();

        CategoriesList.Add(new Categories() { Name = "Data 1", ID = "1" });
        CategoriesList.Add(new Categories() { Name = "Data 2", ID = "2" });
        CategoriesList.Add(new Categories() { Name = "Data 3", ID = "3" });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there is an issue with your getter and setter. It is not properly updating the value once it is changed. I have done by using `INotifyPropertyChanged` and it is working fine.

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App"
    x:Class="App.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CategoriesList}">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            HeightRequest="150"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Button
                                Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
  namespace App
  {
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
        }

    }
}
```

**MainPageViewModel:**

```
 public class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<CategoriesModel> _Categories;
    public ObservableCollection<CategoriesModel> CategoriesList
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Categories;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Categories != value)
            {
                this._Categories = value;
                SetPropertyValue(ref _Categories, value);

            }
        }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {

        CategoriesList = new ObservableCollection<CategoriesModel>
        {
            new CategoriesModel() { Name = "Data 1", ID = "1" },
            new CategoriesModel() { Name = "Data 2", ID = "2" },
            new CategoriesModel() { Name = "Data 3", ID = "3" },
            new CategoriesModel() { Name = "Data 4", ID = "4" },
            new CategoriesModel() { Name = "Data 5", ID = "5" },
            new CategoriesModel() { Name = "Data 6", ID = "6" },
            new CategoriesModel() { Name = "Data 7", ID = "7" }
        };
    }
}
```

**My BaseViewModel which extent the INotifyPropertyChanged:**

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanges([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void SetPropertyValue<T>(ref T bakingFiled, T value, [CallerMemberName] string proertyName = null)
    {
        bakingFiled = value;
        OnPropertyChanges(proertyName);

    }

}
```

All the view model class extend the BaseViewModel in order to access the `SetPropertyValue()` method.

**Output:**

[image: OutPut]

Comment: So i would then replace INotifyPropertyChanged on the viewmodel i am using with "BaseViewModel" then? Would i need to add anymore in that viewmodel or?

Comment: No, You don't need to add any more. Just replace with my code. Check my updated code.

Comment: This is so strange. I copy the exact code but i see no items being displayed. How does ur xaml look?

Comment: Do use the stacklayout binding?

Comment: So strange. Not showing for me. Must be something else that is causing this issue of mine. I will investigate for a bit

Comment: `BindingContext="{Binding viewBind, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`also FYI i am binding it in xaml. And it works for other bindable objects, but not this one.

Comment: If it is not working then bind the data the way i did.

Comment: I am using IoC containers so i cannot follow that design. But the design i have works with other bindable objects, but not this one for some strange reason. I will investige a bit

Comment: Okay now i see it. When i did not use absolutelayout i see it. This is strange

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez, Great! you did it (Y) Happy Coding!

Comment: Haha yes. I think i probably had it working without your changes. But the layout made it so i didnt see it for some reason. Appreciate your code, because i think a BaseViewModel is the better design? I am thinking of replacing all my current viewmodels with the baseviewmodel now instead.

Comment: Yeah, BaseViewModel provides the facility like reusability of code. That is why I prefer inheritance to reduce code repetition.

Comment: Yea exactly :) Great! Thanks for the knowledge

Comment: Does it scroll for you? I have same thing horizontally, we objects going far away to the right and I can't make it scroll. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it does for me.

Comment: Very nicely explained post. Well done and many thanks